# Use of 'the' before of-phrases

Tags: articles, definite-article

When is it necessary to use 'the' before the words preceding *of-phrases*? I've also noticed in some sentences that there is no 'the' before the words preceding of-phrases. When should we not use *the* even if there is an of-phrase? 
For example:

(i) You can park your car in *(No 'the' here)* front of my house.

(ii) You can phone me in *(No 'the' here)* case of need. Day or night.

"In case of" and "in front of" are complex prepositions. I've also noticed that there is no use of *the* in some sentences before the words preceding of-phrases which are not complex prepositions. I don't remember their examples.

(iii) *The* biography of Albert Einstein is very interesting. (*The* is used here.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no 'rule' covering this, only atomic idioms. Looking at your three examples:

(i) *In front of X* is what some grammarians call a “complex preposition” because the entire phrase acts like a preposition meaning “(spatially) before X”—in fact, *in front of* has almost entirely replaced *before* in this sense in US vernacular.
 *In the front of X* is a entirely different matter: this is a prepositional phrase headed by *in*, which takes the noun phrase *the front* as its object; *of X* is another prepositional phrase modifying *front*. For instance:

> The living room is in the front of the house.  ... *that is, inside the house, in its forward part facing the street.*
>   You'll find the letter in the front of the second drawer. ... *that is, inside the drawer, in the part closest to you as you draw it out.*

(ii) *In case of X* is similarly distinguished from *in the case of X*. *In case of X*, without *the*, *in case of* is a fixed phrase (complex preposition) meaning “in the event of X” or “if X happens”—in your example, “if need arises”.  Again, *in **the** case of X* is an ordinary preopositional phrase followed by another prepositional phrase modifying the object, *case*, a noun meaning “instance” or “circumstances” or “matter”:

> In the case of the South Tirol, things fell out quite differently than in Czechoslovakia.

(iii) In *The biography of Albert Einstein*, *biography* is an ordinary noun modified by an ordinary prepositional phrase.

Comment: +1.  Note particularly the difference between "in *the* front of the second drawer" and "in front of the second drawer".

Comment: Can I suppose except some complex preposition, in the cases when there is a of-phrase, we should use "the" before the noun?